# Search and view documents from one site collection to another site collection in one web application

Tags: 2010, document-library, site-collection, enterprise-search

- I created two site collection in one web application with two seperate content dbs

  1. sitecol1
     2.sitecol2
  2. configured enterprise search in sharepoint and will run full crawl and incremental crawl for this web applicaton
  3. users upload documents to doc libraries in these two site collections.

Here i have question :
can users able to view documents from sitecol2 to those documents exists in sitecol1 (sitecol1 in different content db)

ex: users open url of second sitecollection http://webapp/sitecol2/
and in search they will enter DOCUMENTID 
this DocmentID exists in sitecollection 1 http://webapp/sitecol1

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just ensure appropriate Search Results (or search scopes if you are on 2010) on the site collection, so they are not limited to 'This site scope' if you connect site collection to search centre from site settings I think that is quickest way.

Comment: Just one clarification, I assumed that users have access to docs on both site collections. If not they will not see the documents in search as search results are security trimmed if served from local sharepoint.